# Passing options to ghci when starting in Emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-platform

So if I want to run a threaded application in ghci I simply pass `-threaded` to ghci when starting. But how can I do this when starting it from inside Emacs? Can I customize the Emacs haskell mode for this?

I suppose so but I can't find any instructions on this? I can't find any reference documentation for emacs lisp. Only the Haskell wiki but there is no *reference* there. I'm not very familiar with (Emacs) lisp, although I'm learning.

I suppose if I could find where the default emacs packages for haskell-platform are installed I could've read through the source to try to figure it out.

Comment: Chris Done has written a wiki for Emacs & Haskell mode : github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki and chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-mode-docs

Comment: You can also use .ghci files : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23973165/917635

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description of `haskell-program-name` notices that "the command can include arguments".

I've just tested it by setting `haskell-program-name` to `ghci -threaded`.