# Modifying Emacs Inferior Haskell processes to enable CPP processing

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghci

If we look at the source of [The random package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) we have a file `Random.hs`. Because of CPP extensions one has to invoke ghci via the following command :

```
ghci -cpp Random.hs
```

Alternatively one can do :

```
ghci -cpp
```

and then from within ghci :

```
Prelude GOA> :load Random
[1 of 1] Compiling System.Random    ( Random.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: System.Random.
```

If I use Emacs Inferior Haskell mode ([Emacs/Inferior Haskell processes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Inferior_Haskell_processes)) and I have
the source :

```
module Main where
import System.Random

gen = (random (mkStdGen 0)) :: (Bool,StdGen)

mymult :: Int -> Int
mymult x = 2 * x

main = do
  print $ mymult 5
```

then upon typing the emacs command :

```
C-c C-l
```

which is `inferior-haskell-load-file`, ghci is opened in a subwindow in emacs. However if from within this window I type `load Random.hs` then I get the error message :

```
*Main GOA> :load Random.hs

Random.hs:1:2: lexical error at character 'i'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I load `Random.hs` taking into account cpp extensions? Or alternatively how do I modify [haskell-mode/inf-haskell.el](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/inf-haskell.el) such that ghci is invoked with the `-cpp` option upon typing `C-c C-l`, so that the command `:load Random.hs` can be executed without error?

Comment: I'm not getting error, when I do `:load Random.hs`. And in the sample code you have provided, I cannot see any reason why you need `-cpp` as option for `ghci`. Invoking it without the option itself works for me.

Comment: @Sibi You mean you can load the `Random.hs` in the zip file in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random without any cpp option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reliable way is certainly to request `CPP`, along with other extensions, in the file header:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP         #-}

#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 701
{-# LANGUAGE Trustworthy #-}
#endif

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- |
-- Module      :  System.Random
-- Copyright   :  (c) The University of Glasgow 2001
-- License     :  BSD-style (see the file LICENSE in the 'random' repository)
```

The `random` package only does this in the `.cabal` file.

The *easiest* way might be to simply turn `CCP` on permanently in all ghci sessions, by adding

```
:set -XCPP
```

to your `~/.ghci` file.